# Proving a Sobolev-type ineqauality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Given $I=(0,1)$ and $u\in W^{2,p}(0,1)$ for $p>1$. I am trying to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$, the following hold:

$$ \|u\|_{L^\infty(I)}+\|u'\|_{L^\infty(I)}\leq \epsilon\|u''\|_{L^p(0,1)}+C_{\epsilon, p}\|u\|_{L^1(0,1)}$$

I have the following idea: I am taking the fact that for any Banach space $X$, $Y$, $Z$, if $X\subset\subset Y$, i.e., $X$ compact embedding in $Y$, and $Y$ is continuous embedding in $Z$, then I have
$$\|u\|_Y\leq \epsilon \|u\|_X+C_\epsilon \|u\|_Z$$
for any $u\in X$. This is my old functional homework and I am sure it is correct. Thus, by taking $X=W^{2,p}(I)$, $Y=C^1([0,1])$, and $Z=L^1(I)$, I have the following result:

$$ \|u\|_{L^\infty(I)}+\|u'\|_{L^\infty(I)}\leq \epsilon\|u\|_{W^{2,p}(I)}+C_{\epsilon, p}\|u\|_{L^1(I)}=\epsilon(\|u''\|_{L^p}+\|u\|_{L^p}+\|u'\|_{L^p})+C_{\epsilon, p}\|u\|_{L^1(I)}$$

Then by using $L^p$ interpolating and Young's inequality, I am able to write
$$\epsilon(\|u\|_{L^p}+\|u'\|_{L^p})\leq \frac{1}{2} (\|u\|_{L^\infty}+\|u'\|_{L^\infty})+ C_{\epsilon,p}(\|u\|_{L^1}+\|u'\|_{L^1})  $$
Combining the result above I have
$$ \|u\|_{L^\infty(I)}+\|u'\|_{L^\infty(I)}\leq \epsilon\|u''\|_{L^p}+C_{\epsilon,p}\|u'\|_{L^1}+C_{\epsilon,p}\|u\|_{L^1}$$
Now looks like I am just one step away from what I want, however, I have no idea how to control the part $C_{\epsilon,p}\|u'\|_{L^1}$ by $C_{\epsilon,p}\|u\|_{L^1}$...Some help is really welcome!!

Comment: You could try to obtain an interpolation inequality of the form $$ \| u'\|_{L^1} \leq C\| u''\|_{L^p}^\alpha \| u\|_{L^1}^{1-\alpha}.$$ Then just apply Cauchy' inequality with $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Or you could note that the space$$X= \{ u\in L^1(0,1) : u''\in L^p(0,1)\}$$ is the same as $W^{2,p}$ with equivalence of norms if we give the first one $\| u\|_{L^1} +\| u''\|_{L^p}$. Now apply your result with this $X$.

Comment: Thx for the hint! I think my problem now is how to prove those are equivalent norm... Actually this is the problem I stuck with in my OP

Comment: Never mind, I found it in Adam, thx!

Comment: On which page of Adams can I find it? Thanks.